# Where are my pictures

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

Every images in the top bar are gone now. Even after I refresh. I would close the page but I don't know how to reproduce the issue.

Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m

Seems like refreshing the page many time did that. I won't test it anymore. I got the *Too many request coming from that IP* page.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Can't reproduce, same browser. Did you try a hard refresh? (Control+R) in the page.

Comment: no-repro here either.

Comment: Does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/sprites.png load for you?

Comment: Yes. Closing the browser and re-opening fixed it. Weird Issue.

Comment: Does http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/topbar-sprite.png load for you?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Maybe the location of those images were being moved on the server and you just happened to load the page at that very time?

Comment: The sprites.png file has the logo at the top of it, and the badges are also in there.

Comment: Reproed here. By refreshing really fast. Chrome Whatever on OS X 10.9.

Comment: @UndotheSnowman Exactly. Dont do it too much you'll get a temp ip ban lol

Comment: @MartijnPieters but he's missing the logo, and badge icons, along with the top bar icons. You're correct, the top bar comes from http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/topbar-sprite.png. Then the badge/logo are from the site specific sprites.png file since those icons change per site, in this case http://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/img/sprites.png

Comment: @StevenV: Ah, yes, sorry. He is missing *both* sprites indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't hammer our load balancers and they won't be mean to you :)  The images are all in sprites now so they shouldn't happen unless you're just hammering that F5 key, that should solve the issue for users in the future.